# CSS fixed sidemenu with images, wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a position fixed `SIDEmenu` on my page.  It contains 100 little images.  Each image is 10px by 10px.

How can I make the images wrap vertically?

I mean if the browser height is 500, then it will show the images in 2 columns, if the browser screen height is 250 then 4 columns...like a vertical word wrap.

Is this possible using HTML and CSS?

Added: =It is a fixed menu bar on the left, with 100 tiny images. I am trying to make it work on the iphone and a computer. The images are to navigate the website, so every image is important. on the iphone the bottom images get cut off, so I wanted to wrap them. so basically I need the menu to be wider when on a smaller screen to fit in all the menu images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is to use css3's media queries:

```
@media (min-height:500px) and (max-height:1000px){
  #sidebar { width:20px; }
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/izihod/1/edit) is a basic example i made, you can try it by resizing your browser (if it supports css3 media queries, of course)

Answer (score 0):

if you float:left your images, and the side bar is a div, with height in %, images will simply float around based on size. I'll try to make an example.

For example here:
http://jsbin.com/isiquw/1/

Comment: Now the sidebar has unlimited width and all the images are just horizontal...is there any way to control sidebar and float the images at the same time?

Comment: I may not have understood the problem clearly. Care to share an example?

Comment: I have no example sorry :(.  It is a fixed menu bar on the left, with 100 tiny images.  I am trying to make it work on the iphone and a computer.  The images are to navigate the website, so every image is important.  on the iphone the bottom images get cut off, so I wanted to wrap them.  so basically I need the menu to be wider when on a smaller screen to fit in all the menu images...

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS properties in your SIDEmenu,

```
.sidemenu {
         width:25%;
         height:auto;
         float:left;
}
```

Remember, use one clear:both after the end of this DIV

Comment: It's another css class, like: .clear{clear:both;}, it's use for removing the floating action just after the class where you have used "float". Use it like this: <div class="clear"></div> after your sidemenu.